# Get the indices of a vector inside another vector

Tags: r

I have a question on how to fill in a matrix by its column names. I think the following example would make it clear what I want.

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
colnames(mat) <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Grape", "Mango")
```

Now I have a new matrix whose row names are a subset of the column names in `mat`, and with an arbitrary order.

```
jmat <- matrix(rnorm(4), nrow = 4, ncol = 1)
rownames(jmat) <- sample(c("Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Mango"))
```

I want to fill the first row of `mat` by the corresponding values in `jmat`. The value of "Apple" in `jmat` should be in the "Apple" column in `mat`, etc. Because there is no "Pear" row in `jmat`, so the "Pear" column in `mat` will still be a `NA`. What is the simplest way of doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `match` function can give the indices of a vector within another vector.

```
> jmat
             [,1]
Grape  -0.2728387
Apple   2.2843550
Mango  -1.3079324
Orange -0.6129420
> match(rownames(jmat), colnames(mat))
[1] 4 1 5 2
> ind <- match(rownames(jmat), colnames(mat))
> mat[1, ind] <- jmat[, 1]
> mat
         Apple    Orange Pear      Grape     Mango
 [1,] 2.284355 -0.612942   NA -0.2728387 -1.307932
 [2,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [3,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [4,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [5,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [6,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [7,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [8,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
 [9,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
[10,]       NA        NA   NA         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Outer join:

```
merge(mat, t(jmat),all=T)
      Apple    Orange      Grape      Mango Pear
1  2.372201 0.8330786 -0.4295133 -0.8425752   NA
2        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
3        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
4        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
5        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
6        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
7        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
8        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
9        NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
10       NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
11       NA        NA         NA         NA   NA
```